# Function with toString method as map key in Typescript

Tags: typescript, dictionary, tostring

I have a function that has defined toString method, but cannot be used as map key. What is the Typescript way? Using toString method works fine, but it's redundant in classic Javascript.

```
const
    type: string = 'SOME_TYPE',
    action = (payload: T) => ({type, payload});

action.toString = () => type;

const map = {    
    [action]: '...' // 'action' must be of 'number', 'symbol' or 'any' type error
};
```

Comment: are you trying indexed class??

Answer (score 0):

...I assume you're asking about redux [FSA](https://github.com/redux-utilities/flux-standard-action)s, but a `toString` method doesn't make  any sense there :/

My current approach is to use the following:

```
const TYPE = 'ACTION.TYPE';

interface Action<T> {
    type: typeof TYPE;
    payload: T;
}

const action = <T>(payload: T): Action<T> => ({
    type: TYPE;
    payload;
});
```

Some [hope](https://medium.com/@martin_hotell/improved-redux-type-safety-with-typescript-2-8-2c11a8062575) is near, a.k.a TS2.8, to save some of the boilerplate though.